# How do you make a mobile web app?

Tags: web-applications, mobile-website, mobile-application

I've been making a web-app lately using phonegap. Having never done this before, I followed the instructions closely by starting out with iOS and doing my coding inside of XCode. This set up a nice big project for me with a whole bunch of stuff I don't know about already taken care of. I can just write content to my heart's content without worrying about what's under the hood.

But now I'm curious. I know the code I'm writing is being rendered by the iOS's mobile browser. How do people make web-apps without PhoneGap and XCode setting up the whole project for them? How do you make just a standard web-app (without hooking into the device's geolocation sensor, etc) that can be opened on any mobile device as a downloaded app?

Answer (score 2):

You could just make the downloaded app behave like a launcher for a web browser, which would then open your web app when run. The web app itself you would have to develop using standard web development techniques.

On Android, this launcher app would be coded in Java (most commonly), and on iOS I believe it is Objective-C

Answer (score 1):

when you say "downloaded app" it sounds like you mean "URL Shortcut to my HTML 5 page" which pretty much any smartphone can do.

so by making any website that follows the >> [HTML5 standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xhtml-basic-20101123/) << you have a mobile web app.

for example, click the link below which points to the Sencha Touch 2 carousel sample

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/carousel/index.html

(Use your mouse like a finger to slide around the images etc.)

There isn't a way to add an "app button" link to your mobile site using a link because that would be too much power for a webpage to mess up people's device home screen simply by clicking a link.

The best you can do is educate your users on how they can add your "app" using the native iOS functionality...

#### First click this button on any webpage you navigate to

[image: step 1]

#### Then click Add to Home Screen button

[image: step 2]

Comment: I guess that's the question then-- how do you create a "URL Shortcut to my HTML5 page" ? Sorry for the delay, was abducted by aliens, back now, can pick up where we left off.